# Link to local Google App Engine database

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, adt

I have created google app engine application and I run it on: 10.0.2.2:8888/ 
but I forgot what is the full link to get to the full list of recrods uploaded to the app engine.

```
http://10.0.2.2:8888/WHAT_SUPPOSE_TO_BE_HERE
```

The App engine was generated automatically by ADT(Eclipse) for Android application.

[image]

Comment: `WHAT_SUPPOSE_TO_BE_HERE` should be a valid url under which you have defined a GET method implementation that returns all records

Comment: @TimCastelijns It was automatically generated, where in what class I should look for it? Please look at edit.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct answer which has to be at least 30 characters long:

```
http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin/
```